# Prove $f(A)\in Mat_{n \times n}$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $A\in Mat_{n\times n}(F)$ be a nilpotent matrix, and $f\in F[x]$ a polynomial such that $f(0)\neq 0$ Prove: $f(A)\in Mat_{n \times n}$ is invertible

I have started with let assume that $f(A)\in Mat_{n \times n}$ is  not invertible $\Rightarrow$ there is no free variable in the minimal polynomial $\Rightarrow$ $0$ is a root of each polynomial has the minimal polynomial divides each $f(A)=0$ in therefore $f(0)=0$ and that is not true

I know that the proof does not flow correctly any ideas?

Due to previous answers I am looking for a proof without Rings

Second try:

$f(0)\neq 0$ $Rightarrow$ W.L.G $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ in general a polynomial with a free variable, therefore $f(A)=A^2+A+1\Rightarrow A$ is upper triangular matrix therefore the determinant$\neq 0$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: you can write $f(A)=f(0)I+AB$ for some matrix $B$.

Comment: For some  *commuting* matrix $B$.

Comment: @Bernard so in this case I can't use it? as $A$ is nilpotent?

Comment: @gbox Note that $B$ is a polynomial in $A$. Such a matrix always commutes with $A$, regardless of whether $A$ is nilpotent or not.

Comment: You can use, because $B$ is actually a polynomial in $A$. Commutation is really no problem, but I wanted to point, that as stated, it's a little incomplete. Remember the binomial formula is valid for commuting matrices only.

Comment: I am sorry, I think I have not learned this yet, why $B$ is a polynomial in $A$?

Comment: maybe I can use some properties of the minimal polynomial? with regard to this general $f\in F[x]$?

Comment: @gbox It is a rather simple property of polynomial - any $f(x)$ can be written as $f(0)+xg(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @Wojowu I have not learned this properties of polynomials, so I can not use it :(

Comment: @gbox You don't really need any property of polynomials - just write down the polynomial and factor out $x$ from all but the constant term (recall that the constant term is $f(0)$).

Comment: @Wojowu ok so $f(x)=f(0)+xg(x)$ and $f(A)=f(0)+A\cdot g(A)$ but what can I say about $g(x)$ it is just a general polynomial ?

Comment: Write out $f$ as $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$, where, in particular, $a_0 = f(0) \neq 0$. If you now write $f$ as $f(x) = f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$, do you now see how to extract $g(x) = (f(x)-f(0))/x$?

Answer (score 1):

Show first that if $N$ is a nilpotent matrix then $I + N$ is invertible. This can be done by guessing a formal inverse

$$ \frac{1}{I + N} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-N)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n (-N)^k $$

and verifying that this indeed works. Slightly more generally, if $a \neq 0$ then $aI + N = a \left(I + \frac{N}{a} \right)$ is also invertible with inverse $\frac{1}{a} \left(I + \frac{N}{a} \right)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{a^{k+1}} N^k.$

Now, writing $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_m x^m$, we have

$$ f(A) = a_0 I + a_1 A + \dots + a_m A^m = a_0 I + B $$

where $B$ is defined by $B = a_1 A + \dots + a_m A^m$ and $a_0 = f(0)$. The binomial theorem can be used to show that the sum of any number of commuting nilpotent matrices is itself nilpotent and so $B$ is nilpotent and $f(A)$ is invertible by the discussion above.

---

Alternatively, $A$ is similar to a strictly upper triangular matrix (this is a weak form of the Jordan form of nilpotent matrices) and so $f(A)$ is a matrix that is similar to an upper triangular matrix whose diagonal elements are $f(0) \neq 0$ which is an invertible matrix.

Comment: Why "$f(A)$ is a matrix that is similar to an upper diagonal matrix"? why is it similar?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are similar (so $A = P^{-1} BP$) then $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are also similar ($f(A) = P^{-1} f(B) P$). If $B$ is an upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries $b_{ii}$ then $f(B)$ is also an upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries $f(b_{ii})$.